# Can't add script to GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have been repeatedly getting an error, when trying to add a script to a gameObject. I have so far tried changing the MonoBehavior class name to what I had as the scripts name, and checked my code for errors, though none are shown in the terminal. Here`s my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
namespace LE
{
public class InputHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
public float horizontal;
public float vertical;
public float moveAmountl;
public float mouseX;
public float mouseY

    PlayerControls inputActions;

    Vector2 movementInput;
    Vector2 cameraInput

    public void private void OnEnable() {
        {
            if (inputActions == null)
            {
                inputActions = new PlayerControls();
                inputActions.PlayerMovement.Movement.performed += inputActions => movementInput = inputActions.ReadValue<Vector2>();
                inputActions.PlayerMovement.Camera.performed += i => cameraInput = i.ReadValue<Vector2>();
            }

            inputActions.Enable(); 
        }
    
    private void private void OnDisable()
     {
        inputActions.Disable();
    }
    }

    public void TickInput(float delta)
    {
        MoveInput(delta);
    }

    private void MoveInput(float delta)
    {
        horizontal = movementInput.x;
        vertical = movementInput.y;
        moveAmountv= Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.Abs(horizontal) + Mathf.abs(vertical));
        mouseX = cameraInput.x;
        mouseY = cameraInput.y;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

It could be this (note typed twice private and public void):

```
 public void private void OnEnable() {

 private void private void OnDisable()
 {
    inputActions.Disable();
 }
```

should be

```
 private void OnEnable() {

 private void OnDisable()
 {
    inputActions.Disable();
 }
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I'll try it. I can't believe I did that.

Comment: Hm. I did that and ended up with the same error “Can’t add script” “cant add script component ‘inputHandler’ because the script class cannot be found. Make sure there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match”

Comment: Is your script called "InputHandler.cs" (Note: Case Sensitive)

Comment: Ahh I can see from your error, if that is Copy pasted that you have called the script itself "inputHandler.cs" with a small "i" - check that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is the case. What should I do to fix it? Change the public class and unity script name or change it in visual studio?

Comment: I managed to change the script name in Visual Studio and Unity, but am still getting the same error.

Comment: Just make sure of 2 things
1) Both names are exactly the same
2) the script can compile, so that it can get updated.

Comment: How could I change the scripts name?

Comment: in the editor right click => rename'